# Uncovering items with changing bullet color

Tags: beamer, lists, color, itemize

In this case consecutive items get covered. How could I change this behaviour so that all items would be black and only bullets would get different colours?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
\begin{itemize}
 \item<1-> First
 \item<2-> Second
 \item<3-> Third
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Desired effect]

Comment: Check the beameruserguide for `alert`. Like `\begin{itemize}[<alert@+>]
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer, adapted from the example in the Beamer user guide, p82:

```
 \documentclass{beamer}

\def\colorize<#1>{%
    \temporal<#1>{%
        \setbeamercolor{item}{fg=blue}%
    }{%
        \setbeamercolor{item}{fg=red}%
    }{%
        \setbeamercolor{item}{fg=blue}%
    }
}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[triangle]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
\begin{itemize}
 \colorize<1> \item First
    \begin{itemize}
        \colorize<2> \item First a
        \colorize<3> \item First b
    \end{itemize}
 \colorize<4> \item Second
 \colorize<5> \item Third 
\end{itemize}
```

There must be a better way of doing it though. Does anyone know how to redefine `\item` so as to get the desired output without having to use an extra command (`\colorize` here) in front of each `\item`?

EDIT:
`\colorize` is now compatible with all levels of `itemize` environments.

Comment: what about the `itemize` inside `itemize`? it's not working!

Comment: I'm not sure I approve of your exclamation mark... Is it supposed to convey urgency or irritation? Anyway, you get the result you want by substituting `item` for `itemize item` in the definition of `\colorize'.

Comment: sorry for the exclamation mark, tomorrow i have to present my thesis and i'm a bit nervous :]